# Add custom block under long description (product.info.description)

Tags: layout, xml, magento2.3.1

I'd like to add a custom block in description tab just after long description field.

I Tried

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.subdescription" template="product/view/subdescription.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change template name like below:  (change Vendor_Module according to your custom module)

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.subdescription" template="Vendor_Module::product/view/subdescription.phtml" group="detailed_info"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Tried this, but there's an exception

`1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Magento_Catalog::product/view/subdescription.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Catalog' block's name: 'product.subdescription'`

Comment: This is subdescription.phtml content

`<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
?>
<h1>SUBDESCRIZIONE</h1>
<?php if ($_product->getData('downloadable')): ?>  
 <div class="product-collateral-itunes" id="downloadable" >      
  <div class="innerdownloadable"><?php echo $_product->getData('downloadable') ?></div>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: @domfitty is your template stored like this `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/view/subdescription.phtml` ?